# Selects move down when there is a inline-block level element next to it

Tags: html, css

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eA9Q9/2/)

Selects move down when there is an inline-block level element next to it. i dont want selects to move down. How can i do that?
html:

```
<select>
    <option value="" >Day</option>
</select><select>
    <option value="" >Month</option>
</select><select>
    <option value="" >Year</option>
</select>
<a href="">Some Text Some Text Some Text Some Text</a>
```

css:

```
   select{
        padding:5px;
        margin:0px;
        height:30px;
        font-size:13px;
    }
    a{
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#000;
        display:inline-block;
        border:1px solid #ccc;
        margin-left:10px;
        line-height:1.28;
        max-width:150px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` as the default is `baseline` for inline items.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eA9Q9/3/)